# Сборка (sourcemap + gulp-combine-mq) - некорректный sourcemap

Tags: gulp

В какое место я бы не ставил `css_cmq`, до или после `sourcemaps.write()` все равно в браузере получаются неверная нумерация строк и файлов для sourcemap. Можно ли как то подружить эти плагины вместе?

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const stylus = require('gulp-stylus');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const css_cmq = require('gulp-combine-mq');

gulp.task('styles', function () {

  return gulp.src('./style/public/main.styl')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(stylus())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(css_cmq())
    .pipe(gulp.dest());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Нет, уже не раз опробовано. Я в свое время решал эту проблему разделением сборки CSS на два таска: один для разработки с `sourcemap`, а другой для продакшена со всеми необходимыми оптимизациями и без `sourcemap`.